# How to model segmentation of a sequence to similar parts?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I guess LSTM is good for sequence modeling but how would you model "clustering" with it? Meaning, the input is a sequence and the output is labels with similar properties (I have labeled data). For example:

```
input:  1 2 1 1 2 1 2 5 6 5 4 5 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 
output: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The problem is how to tell the model to learn differences and not the particular example, as a new example could have totally different values. I could have taught it to predict the N*(N-1)/2 pairwise differences (similar non similar) but it will not learn the dynamics.

Comment: "The problem is how to tell the model to learn differences and not the particular example, as a new example could have totally different values." - can you change the input from the raw value to the sample-to-sample diff?

Comment: @kbrose I don't think so. What I am looking for is kind of a Hidden Markov Model but one which is not necessarily markovian and which I can train on labeled data and test on data with totally different states and emissions. It's like "learning how to cluster".

Comment: is the sequence order important? otherwise, you can use some hierarchical clustering or something similar as https://github.com/Borda/pySeqClust

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reframed as a binary classification by ignoring the order, and then a decision tree algorithm can learn to separate the groups with perfect accuracy.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# Define training data
training_data    = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
training_targets = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)

# Train a descision tree with scikit-learn
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)
clf.fit(training_data, training_targets)

# Let's if the model can predict unseen data
test_data_low = np.array([0]).reshape(1, -1)
prediction = clf.predict(test_data_low)
assert prediction == 1

test_data_high = np.array([7]).reshape(1, -1)
prediction = clf.predict(test_data_high)
assert prediction == 2
```

The ability of a model to learn to generalize (i.e., predict total new values) can be increased by increasing regularization. In the above example, one method to increase regularization is limiting the depth of the decision tree. I have set the depth to be a single split, aka decision stump. A decision stump is the most regularized version of a decision tree.